# Win11: Notepad: Cursor seems to disappear?

Tags: windows, windows-10, notepad

I am a heavy user of Notepad

I find the cursor is hard to see (it is very skinny).

I found that in Settings, I can thicken the cursor (however, this setting does not affect all apps, for example the cursor in this editor here on superuser is NOT affected by the cursor settings in Settings. (The thickness IS changed in notepad.)

However, in both Notepad and in other apps, after 30 or 60 seconds, the cursor "disappears"

In Notepad, it goes completely invisible. Basically, it stops blinking in the "off" position, so is invisible.

In other apps, like Zoom chat, it stops blinking in the On position. So it is there, but doesn't grab the eye because it is not blinking.

I want the cursor to ALWAYS blink, in ALL apps, FOREVER.

How do I do this?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I don't see a link?

Comment: Oops!  That was supposed to be [Cursor stops blinking after a few seconds on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1436937/1210833)