# Win11: Notepad & Other Apps: Cursor disappears and/or stops blinking

Tags: windows-11, notepad

I am a heavy user of Notepad

I find the cursor is hard to see (it is very skinny).

I found that in Settings, I can thicken the cursor (however, this setting does not affect all apps, for example the cursor in this editor here on superuser is NOT affected by the cursor settings in Settings. (The thickness IS changed in notepad.)

However, in both Notepad and in other apps, after 30 or 60 seconds, the cursor "disappears"

In Notepad, it goes completely invisible. Basically, it stops blinking in the "off" position, so is invisible.

In other apps, like Zoom chat, it stops blinking in the On position. So it is there, but doesn't grab the eye because it is not blinking.

I want the cursor to ALWAYS blink, in ALL apps, FOREVER.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a function of a few things...

The "CaretTimeout" value seems to have gone down in Win11 to perhaps two seconds (used to be 5 in earlier versions of Windows).

And many apps have their own behavior, but in Win11, Notepad had a lot of tweaks, and the cursor seems skinnier (even when it is blinking).

This may be the fix:
https://superuser.com/a/1439287/15466

NOTE: I have NOT figured out the fix to this at all. The problem is wide open for me.